# Angular 2: Route parameter changes, reload the same page?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a route with a parameter, when going to the page /users/123 where 123 is the parameter the ngOnInit is called, I get my parameter and I call my method to get the user.

However, when I'm on that page and I click a second link /users/456 then the ngOnInit is not called anymore (because that page is already instantiated). So without ngOnInit I can't get the route parameter and can't call my method to get the user.

If I go to /users/123, then to /home, then to /users/456, it works obviously.

What do I have to use to make sure the function that gets the parameter and gets the user is ALWAYS called even if I'm already on the same page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use subscriber `route.params` to listen the param's change.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class DemoPage {
    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    ngOnInit() {
            this._route.params.forEach(params => {
                    let userId = params["userId"];
                    //call your function, like getUserInfo()
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Params is an Observable. So you only have to subscribe once to the observable and everytime the parameters change, you get notified.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => /* load your user e.g. getUser(params['id']) */)
    .subscribe(user => this.user = user);
}
```

You also need to import ActivatedRoute and Params

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnInit` is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

For watch route params use `ActivatedRoute`.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        console.log(params); // Your params called every change
    });
}
```

Don't forget to import:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
```

Read more about OnInit: [OnInit - ts - API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnInit-class.html)

Read more about ActivatedRoute: [ActivatedRoute - ts - API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry guys, I was calling my get user outside of the activatedRoute callback.

This is correct:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class DemoPage {
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
        this._route.params.forEach(params => {
                let userId = params["userId"];
                getUserInfo(userId);
        });
    }
}
```

What I did was:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class DemoPage {
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
        var userId = "";
        this._route.params.forEach(params => {
            userId = params["userId"];                    
        });

        getUserInfo(userId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution in my case is worked perfect :

this.ActiveRout.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
`DOCTYPE : number;`

```
    this.DOCTYPE = + param.get('DocType');

  ` and in my page i want to input value to be change by DOCTYPE value that will call 
    the DocsTypeServ to return the name of DOCUMENT TYPE BY ID (DOCTYPE)`

   this.DocsTypeServ.readByID(this.DOCTYPE).subscribe((data: CDocsType[]) => {
     this.DocumentType_Value = (data.find(x => x.ID == this.DOCTYPE).NAME).toString();
   }
   );
})
```